# jQuery validator add method undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

https://jsfiddle.net/c50m4pos/1/

Simple validator works, but once i get to add a little more things like above, things starts to act strange.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {



  $('#testform').validate({
    rules: {
      testinput: {
        required: true,
        textonly: true,
        messages: {
          required: 'Input is required'
        }
      }
    }

  });

  $.validator.addMethod(
    "textonly",
    function(value, element) {
      var valid = false;
      var check = /[^-'\.a-zA-Z0-9\s\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02AE]/.test(value);
      if (check == false)
        valid = true;
      return this.optional(element) || valid;
    },
    "Please only enter letters, digits, spaces, periods, or hyphens."
  );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="testform">
  <p>
    <label>testinput 1</label>
    <label for="testinput" class="error" id="testinput-error"></label>
    <input id="testinput" name="testinput">
  </p>

  <button type='submit'>
    Submit
  </button>


</form>
```

Safari Returns error

> [Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.validator.methods[d].call').  Exception occurred when checking element testinput, check the 'messages' method.

Firefox says

> TypeError: a.validator.methods[d] is undefined ...f){e={method:d,parameters:f[d]};try{if(c=a.validator.methods[d].call(this,i,

The new method "textonly" works, and it displays the error message gracefully. However, when the input field is re-validated( you re-input text without illegal characters), the error occurs.

I've tried adding "textonly" custom message under textinput rules but it still errors.
How do i fix this?

Comment: The `messages` object is a **sibling** of `rules`... it does not belong inside of `rules` as you've done.

Answer (score 0):

The `messages` object is a sibling of `rules`... it does not belong inside of `rules` as you've done.

```
$('#testform').validate({
    rules: {
        testinput: {
            required: true,
            textonly: true,
        }
    },
    messages: {  // sibling of 'rules' object
        testinput: {
            required: 'Input is required',
            textonly: 'letters only'  // over-ride '.addMethod()' message
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO**:  https://jsfiddle.net/c50m4pos/2/

Please refer to [documentation for `messages`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#messages) to see proper usage.